# vcs plugin for vim?

Tags: vim, plugins

which VCS (git, hg) plugin for vim do you recommend?

Comment: What do you mean by "VCS plugin"?  What kind of actions do you expect it to do?

Comment: VCS=Version control system. I search a plugin to integrate git to vim

Comment: I know what VCS means.  But I don't know what "integrate git to vim" means.  What do you expect from such "integration"?

Comment: The Emacs-modules for VC-integration contains support for diffing, annotation (svn blame), and a couple of other thing.s

Answer (score 4):

For git, I recommend [fugitive](http://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive). I especially like the nice integration of the diff mode, (:Gdiff) which makes it possible to do interactive add.

Answer (score 3):

[vcscommand.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90) is what you're looking for.  I haven't used it with Git or Mercurial, but I do use it with Subversion to great effect.  Check out [the documentation](http://mg.pov.lt/vim/doc/vcscommand.txt), which details all of the commands; the mapping section tells you how to invoke them:

```
|<Leader>|ca VCSAdd
|<Leader>|cn VCSAnnotate
|<Leader>|cN VCSAnnotate!
|<Leader>|cc VCSCommit
|<Leader>|cD VCSDelete
|<Leader>|cd VCSDiff
|<Leader>|cg VCSGotoOriginal
|<Leader>|cG VCSGotoOriginal!
|<Leader>|ci VCSInfo
|<Leader>|cl VCSLog
|<Leader>|cL VCSLock
|<Leader>|cr VCSReview
|<Leader>|cs VCSStatus
|<Leader>|cu VCSUpdate
|<Leader>|cU VCSUnlock
|<Leader>|cv VCSVimDiff
```

I usually do most of these things in a terminal beside my Vim window, but annotate (\cN if you're using the default leader) pops up the annotation in a new split, which is super useful

Comment: VCSCommand works nicely with CVS and SVN, but its git integration isn't all that hot as it tries to `commit` the current file, rather than working with git's stage-commit workflow.